# No module named 'casADI' in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to run a python script that use casADI in Binder but I have the following error: No module named 'casADI'. Should I include casADI manually? If I should, how can I do this?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-670886d637ab> in <module>
 1 import casADI as ca
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 7)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'casADI'
```

Note. This is not my script, I found this script in a book (it's probably Python 2). In addition, I´m using Jupyter in my browser (Binder)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Do update your status so I know whats going on

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to install `casADI` then follow the instruction [here](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/InstallationInstructions#option-3-casadi-on-conda)

It's as simple as performing the following in your conda environment

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda install casadi
```

> It is given that builds are available for Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6, and numpy 1.12 so you should be fine either Python 2.x or 3.x